# BASH_REMATCH not outputting a match

Tags: linux, bash, shell

### Context

I'm trying to use regex to pull out the repository name from a github https clone link, and I can't seem to get the BASH_REMATCH to work.

For context, I'm writing this as a .sh file and running it in Git Bash.

### Code Logic

As you'll see below, I basically feed in a clone https link, and also provide the regex pattern. I tried this on https://regex101.com/ and the regex correctly pulls out the final bit of the string:

> /liam_test_3.git

With it also pulling out the specific capture group of just the repository name:

> liam_test_3

But the code I've tried to test below is defaulting to the "else" statement and outputting "no match".

### Code

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# $1 = SSH Clone Link
# $2 = Github Organisation


CLONE="https://github.cloud.companyname.com/Organisation/liam_test_3.git";
re="\/(?!.*\/)(.*).git";

echo "$CLONE"
echo "$re"

if [[ $CLONE =~ $re ]]
then 
    repo_dir=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    echo "Your repo name is $repo_dir"
else
    echo "No Match"
fi;
```

Comment: By the way, you don't need an RE for this, try `echo "${CLONE##*/}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `re="([^/]*)\.git";` This will match the final part of the url (everything after the last /), and capture the repository name.

Note that you need to escape the **.** before the git otherwise this would match the first occurrence of *git* in the url, as the **.** would match the 2nd **/** of **https://github**